# Correctness of constructors and operators in terms of efficiency (Matrix class)

Tags: c++

I am implementing my matrix class. How can I change my constructors and operators (especially move) to be as efficient as possible without memory leaks?

```
template <typename T>
    class Matrix
    {
    private:
        T *data = nullptr;
        const size_t rows;
        const size_t cols;
```

And constructors (I implement according to the rule of five, I missed the usual constructors, I left the main ones - copying and moving)

```
Matrix(const Matrix &other_) : data(new T[other_.rows * other_.cols]), rows(other_.rows), cols(other_.cols)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < rows * cols; i++)
            {
                data[i] = other_.data[i];
            }
        }

        Matrix &operator=(const Matrix &other)
        {
            if (&other == this)
            {
                return *this;
            }
            if (rows != other.rows && cols != other.cols)
            {
                std::cout << "Error assigning matrices of different sizes" << std::endl;
                std::exception();
            }

            clean();

            rows = other.rows;
            cols = other.cols;

            for (int i = 0; i < rows * cols; i++)
            {
                data[i] = other.data[i];
            }

            return *this;
        }

        Matrix(Matrix &&other) noexcept : rows((other.rows)), cols((other.cols)), data(other.data)
        {
            other.data = nullptr;
            other.rows = 0;
            other.cols = 0;
        }

        Matrix &operator=(Matrix &&other) noexcept
        {
            if (&other == this)
            {
                return *this;
            }
            if (rows != other.rows && cols != other.cols)
            {
                std::cout << "Error assigning matrices of different sizes" << std::endl;
                exit(-1);
            }

            clean();

            std::swap(data, other.data);
            std::swap(rows, other.rows);
            std::swap(cols, other.cols);

            other.data = nullptr;
            other.rows = 0;
            other.cols = 0;

            return *this;
        }
```

You can't use standard library containers, I manage resources

Comment: The move constructor can use `swap` too. Potentially that saves a `delete` + `new` when the source matrix is reused.

Comment: In the move assignment what does `clean()` do? I assume it calls `delete[] data`. Why do you swap the 3 members only to then zero them in other? Drop the `clean` and the assignment, just do the 3 swaps.

Comment: Yes, clean() clears data and sets rows and columns to zero. But it's not very clear why we don't need to use this function in the move operator, don't we need to clear the memory and zero out the rows and columns before moving the data?

Comment: If you copy data from other matrix, you don't need to `clean()` since all values will be reassigned. If you want to ensure that both copied matrices share the exact same count of rows and columns, you must use an OR `||` logic operator instead of AND `&&` here : `if (rows != other.rows && cols != other.cols)`

Comment: When you pass an object to a function using move semantic then the object might be moved or not, it's in some indeterminate state after the call. When you use just the 3 `swap` calls in the move constructor you swap the source and destination leaving `other` in a perfectly valid state. The destructor of `other` in the caller will later do the `clean()` for you.

Comment: That sounds like you saved nothing. But the caller could then reuse the matrix by, for example, assigning something to it (no move). PS: Since you only allow assigning matrixes with the same row/col count why not make them template parameters? That would give compile time errors when you assign wrong instead of runtime.

Comment: Okay, I'll add your comments. Does the rest look effective? Later I will make an iterator for the matrix.